# How to assign value of variable inside XHR.onload fuction outside the fuction to javascript varaible? in django

Tags: javascript, json, django-rest-framework

I need help to assign value of 'hmmm' variable inside xhr.onload fuction to the js variable 'questions' outside xhr function,the value of 'hmmm' is json object whose structure is similar to the 'questions' variable outside function.
i have tried searching for it but haven't yet come across  good solution.

is there any way to assign value of 'hmmm' variable to 'questions' variable

Much appreciated .

'''

```
   let quiz = document.forms["welcome_form"]["quiz"].value;
   const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()
    const method='GET'
    const url="/quiz/dock/{{q.slug}}"
    console.log(url)
    const responseType='json'
    xhr.responseType=responseType
    xhr.open(method,url)
    xhr.onload=function(){    
        console.log(xhr.response)
        const Server_response=xhr.response
        let hmm=Server_response.quiz_list
        console.log(hmm)
        
    }
    xhr.send()


    let questions = [
      {
        id: 1,
        question: "What is the full form of RAM ?",
        answer: "Random Access Memory",
        options: [
          "Random Access Memory",
          "Randomely Access Memory",
          "Run Aceapt Memory",
          "None of these"
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        question: "What is the full form of CPU?",
        answer: "Central Processing Unit",
        options: [
          "Central Program Unit",
          "Central Processing Unit",
          "Central Preload Unit",
          "None of these"
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        question: "What is the full form of E-mail",
        answer: "Electronic Mail",
        options: [
          "Electronic Mail",
          "Electric Mail",
          "Engine Mail",
          "None of these"
        ]
      }
    ];

    console.log(questions)
    let question_count = 0;
    let points = 0;

    window.onload = function() {
      show(question_count);

    };

    function next() {

      
      // if the question is last then redirect to final page
      if (question_count == questions.length - 1) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("time", time);
        clearInterval(mytime);
        window.location.href='/quiz/end/'+quiz
        
      }
      console.log(question_count);

      let user_answer = document.querySelector("li.option.active").innerHTML;
      // check if the answer is right or wrong
      if (user_answer == questions[question_count].answer) {
        points += 10;
        sessionStorage.setItem("points", points);
      }
      console.log(points);

      question_count++;
      show(question_count);
    }

    function show(count) {
      let question = document.getElementById("questions");
      let [first, second, third, fourth] = questions[count].options;

      question.innerHTML = `
      <h2>Q${count + 1}. ${questions[count].question}</h2>
      <ul class="option_group">
      <li class="option">${first}</li>
      <li class="option">${second}</li>
      <li class="option">${third}</li>
      <li class="option">${fourth}</li>
    </ul> 
      `;
      toggleActive();
    }

    function toggleActive() {
      let option = document.querySelectorAll("li.option");
      for (let i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
        option[i].onclick = function() {
          for (let i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
            if (option[i].classList.contains("active")) {
              option[i].classList.remove("active");
            }
          }
          option[i].classList.add("active");
        };
      }
    }


 </script>'''
```

Comment: The goal is to assign json response of a django view fuction in this page to 'questons' variable ....The django fuction view is called at url:const url="/quiz/dock/{{q.slug}}" Therefore i need to assign value of 'hmmm' variable inside onload fuction to 'questions' variable outisde it.

Comment: Read the duplicate. It's not about assigning to the variable, it's about ***when*** that data will be available. You need to put the code that requires the data to where the data is available, not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you deceze.. It's as you said I just called the starting fuction for main js in async fuction call and it worked....